# Force read system call to block

Tags: c++, serial-port, system-calls

I have a program that reads from and writes to serial port. I have a reader thread that reads data and supplies informations to shared memory. The reader thread should sleep until data is available. So I want to make `read()` system call to block calling thread. Considering man pages, unless you supply `O_NONBLOCK` to `open`, `read` should always block. But I have an active thread which in it `read` returns `-1` continuously. ALso changing `VTIME` and `VMIN` does not make a difference.  This is how port is opened:

```
fd = open(portName.str().c_str()/*/dev/ttyS2*/, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd < 0) // if open is not successful
    {
        cerr << ERROR << "Unable to open `" << portName << "'." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << INFO << "Port " << portName.str() << " successfully opened."
                << endl;
        cout << INFO << "Configuring port..." << endl;
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0);
        struct termios port_settings; // structure to store the port settings in
        cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B38400); // set baud rate
        cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B38400); // set baud rate
        port_settings.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // disable H/W flow control
        port_settings.c_lflag &= ~( ISIG | // disable SIGxxxx signals
                IEXTEN | // disable extended functions
                ECHO | ECHOE); // disable all auto-echo functions
        port_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON ; // raw mode
        port_settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // raw output
        port_settings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // disable S/W flow control;
            // Following values do not change timout in runtime:
        port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 2; // wait 0.2 second to get data - 
        port_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

        port_settings.c_cflag = (port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE) | CS8; // set data byte size
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // set stop bit 1
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // set no parity
        port_settings.c_iflag |= IGNPAR; // ignore parity
        port_settings.c_iflag &= ~(INPCK | ISTRIP | PARMRK);

        // Set
        if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings) < 0)
        {
            cerr << ERROR << "Unable to configure serial port." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << INFO << "Port `" << portName.str()
                    << "' configuration was successful." << endl;
        }
```

And in reader thread:

```
byte buffer[256];
while (true)
{
    int packetSize = read(fd, buffer, 256);
    if (packetSize > 0)
    { 
      // use data - this code is never run 
    }
    else 
    {
       // print error - we're always here. no matter how long timout is
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider here.

First, read can return for a number of reasons.  Interrupts of any kind will cause read to unblock and return -1, also there could be an issue with the file. Check errno variable for more information on why it is returning -1.  Description of possible errno values are in the [read man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Second, after you've solved the above, when data is available read is not guaranteed to give you an entire network packet in a single read, so you might need to reassemble from multiple reads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested with `perror` and result is `Invalid argument`

Comment: That means `fd` is not a valid file descriptor.

Comment: ...and errno is `EBUSY (16)`

Comment: yes, sound like a bad descriptor.  You should look into how you are passing the descriptor from one thread to the other to make sure it is still valid in the reader thread.

Comment: Hmm... I have no idea about how to pass a descriptor between threads. I'm going to search about. Thanks