# Share a file descriptor between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have many POSIX threads, two reader that read from serial port and others write to same port using a file descriptor. How can I share same descriptor between them? I have synchronized read/write and write/write actions between all threads by semaphores.

**Note:** I'm supposing a file descriptor should be shared between threads of same process but my code fails to run with a `EBUSY` error when second reader tries to read from port. (asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889609/force-read-system-call-to-block) before)

**Update**

This is a little weird situation, even if only one thread is present at runtime, any call to `read()` after `write()` return `-l` with `EBUSY` error. Maybe I'm asking wrong question. There should be a some kind of `flush` after each `write()` to make sure that device is free? or somehow force `write()` to block?

Comment: why do you need concurrent accessing? can't you avoid that situation by having this done by a single thread and all others queuing read/write commands to it?

Comment: File descriptors _are_ shared. Can you please add some code to your question, to show how you do the locking and reading? And of course think about a re-design where only one thread (it may even be a completely new thread) does the reading.

Comment: @didierc It will be very hard to design such a situation

Comment: why would it be difficult?

Comment: @didierc I need to change a complex mechanical control & balance system which I have no idea how it works, because my field is computer science and I have no knowledge of mechanics. I can only analyze system implementation.

Comment: I don't see why doing sequential instead concurrent port IO would have  a negative impact on the "complex mechanical control & balance system".

Comment: @didierc I'm pretty sure current design is not a good one, and best possible design will be much more simpler than current system. But the problem is that I do not understand mechanism clearly, so I can't redesign it. We need time and effort to design + implement + test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the `EBUSY` return code signals that the port is in use, and should be queried again later. Your threads should just wait a little bit and try again, until the command passes.

You sort of mention in one of your comments that the system behind the port is a mechanical one, which would explain why it could take a little while for a command to get processed.

I think the "one thread to handle IO" is the best approach. Each read/write would block the thread and avoid the `EBUSY` problem you are witnessing. All you would have left to do is implement a command queue (very easy with `std::queue` or similar and just just one mutex to sync all accesses).

**UPDATE**: reading your update, I guess that `EBUSY` are just the sign that commands are really slow to execute, and finish a little while after the system call returned, to the point that even when one single thread is doing IO, it may experience it. As I said at the beginning of my answer, have the thread wait a bit before reissuing its command, and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open file with 'O_NONBLOCK' flag.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid from. I need blocking